# Как подключить vue-suggestions в nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет!
При попытке подключить nuxt через ssr получаю:

```
error unexpected token
```

При ssr: false нукст видет его просто как функцию

Кто сталкивался с этим и нашли ли решение?
Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Vue-suggestions экспортирует компонент, а не плагин.
Вам нужно самостоятельно обернуть компонент в плагин и в конфиге nuxt'а подключать его:
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins

Либо импортировать непосредственно в компоненте, как указано в [README](https://github.com/iamstevendao/vue-suggestion#getting-started).